# How can I repurpose a typeform for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-forms

I am attempting to re-code a response form from a premium form generation website. The nature of the problem is in grabbing the form/input values and sending them to a free form system such as google sheets/forms.

The way (as you probably know) that this is traditionally done is through having a single `<form>` container with all `<input>` fields within and a singular submission button, however the way in which this form is laid out, the `<input>` tags do not have a `<form>` container.

I probably cannot provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as my knowledge on this matter isn't rich enough to delete enough collateral to stem to the problem. i.e. there are many variables that factor on the function on this form that may alter the nature of the problem.

As of yet I have not been able to isolate how the button submits the `<input>` however I suspect that it lies within `default.js`.

Please find the reduced project (minimal number of questions with 2 input types) here for [download on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1broVrgD3VE6O8j3DgUPyt7l0NbU5O9E1/view?usp=sharing).

The ideal scenario would to be able to send form data to a Google Sheet using the Google Forms `<input>` `formaction` and `name` codes.

Comment: Related to [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47522936/472495) (10K users only). Without code in the question itself, this is likely to be put on hold. The reason we have this guideline is that if the file locker files are deleted, an administrative effort is created where someone has to edit or delete the question. It happens quite a lot, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, do you have any suggestions as to how I might amend the question with my limited knowledge to recreate the problem as a MCVE?

Comment: I wish I could help further, but my expertise is as an editor here - I don't use Google products. I took a look at your zip file, and even the form on its own is 38K, which would exceed the 30K maximum question size here. The `default.js` file is even worse at 164K, and I very much doubt anyone is going to look through that. It looks like it's been through a size stripper as well, so var/func names are one and two characters in length, and there's no comments - not very friendly to debug.

Comment: I don't use TypeForm either, but by coincidence recently looked at it. Why can you not use this? I would imagine that has data collection facilities (isn't that the point of these online form systems)? Maybe that would be easier than trying to convert what you have to Google Forms?

Comment: For a casual freelancer on the side, $70aud/mo for the PRO+ plan isn’t particularly viable for such a small detail. I was looking through the code (I had been HTML, CSS& JS coding on and off for 2ish years) and I wanted to adapt it to Google Forms so I could simply extend the code manually and make it whatever I wanted. I guess posting the question to the community was a long shot anyway in my mind.